# Need to update a pick-list field based on the reminder date field

Tags: apex, batch, picklist, update

I have a requirement to update a pick list value when a record meets the reminder date. 
There is a field called reminder date in my object and when this reminder date is equal to my current date then a pick list field needs to be updated.
This check needs to be happen on a daily basis.

I know when can achieve this using Batch, but i dont want to do this that way.
Is there any other way this can be achieved?

Thanks for sharing your input.

Thanks
Venkatesh

Comment: I think you can use Scheduled Apex if you want to update daily...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [time-based workflow](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245&language=en_US) to perform this update. Keep in mind that rules are only evaluated when the record is created or modified, so you'll have to think about how the date component plays in. From there, you can attach a field update to the workflow that uses the specified date field to set the new value.